# n回目のハイフンとマッチさせたい

Tags: 正規表現

正規表現でn回目のハイフンとマッチさせたいです。
例えば下記のURLの左から二回目のハイフンから右`-fdfd-fd`とマッチし削除する正規表現を知りたいです。

一回目からマッチさせるなら`-.*`なのですが。

https://www.example.com/a-12345-fdfd-fd

Comment: 全くの方向の違いかつ根本的な指摘で恐縮ですが、割と簡単な文字列処理ですのでわざわざ正規表現でなくても、ハイフンで分割して先頭と2番めをまたハイフンで結合して戻せばよいかなと思いました。

Comment: まさにそのやり方ですが、一括処理できないものかと思い質問しました。

Comment: どの言語・ライブラリの正規表現を想定しておられますか? 正規表現の詳細実装は千差万別ですので、その辺を指定した方が、より適切な回答がつきやすいかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

2回目にマッチさせる正規表現の例です

```
^[^-]*-[^-]*-
```

2回目から右の削除はperlならこれでいけます

```
s/^([^-]*-[^-]*)-.+$/\1/
```

Comment: 削除は正規表現だと厳しいのですかね？
^[^-]*-[^-]*- これを除いたものとマッチさせるやり方はありますか？

Comment: 一般に正規表現はパターンマッチのために使うもので、削除や置き換えのような処理は言語側の機能です。^[^-]*-[^-]*- これを除いたものとマッチさせるには、それ自体もマッチさせる必要があります